# PHP How to check if an array key equals a certain value?

Tags: php

How do I check that an array key equals a value with an array like this:

`Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [subCategory] => All Headphones [description] => [image] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [subCategory] => Behind-the-Neck Headphones [description] => [image] => ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [subCategory] => Clip-On Headphones [description] => [image] => ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [subCategory] => Earbud Headphones [description] => [image] => ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [subCategory] => Kids' Headphones [description] => [image] => ) )`

I've tried using this code:

```
if(array_key_exists('subCategory',$array) {
          echo "Exists";
}
```

Comment: what you are trying to access are not array keys but rather object properties. so tell us first what you actually want to achieve ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That wont work because you have an array of standard objects... the only array keys even present are integers. So the question is what are you trying to detect? If you want to check the if an object has the `subCategory` property you can do `isset($obj->subCategory)`. If you want to ensure that each object in your array has that property then you need to loop:

```
function hasSubCategory($array){
  foreach($array as $element) {
    if(!isset($element->subCategory)){
      return false; // if any object doesnt have the property
    }
  }

  return true; // if all objects have the property
}
```

I dont think thats what you really want to do though, some more info would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using fetch_object(). This gives you array of objects. If you want to work with arrays use fetch_assoc()
To use array_key_exists you need to loop the result because it is multidimensional array.